# Return information from a database with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, symfony

J'utilise Symfony comme Backend et Angular comme Frontend. J'essaie d'afficher la liste de tous les utilisateurs de ma base de données postgresql dans un tableau. Le navigateur affiche uniquement l'information passée dans la balise .

![display example]([View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mojwf.jpg)) 
[image]
here is the eb_user.ts file where I declared the user

```
import {EbRole} from './role';

export class eb_user {
    id: number;
    nom: string;
    prenom: string;
    tel: string;
    mail: string;
    domaine: string;
    x_eb_role : string;


    constructor(){
        this.id = null;
        this.nom = '';
        this.prenom = '';
        this.tel = '';
        this.mail = '';
        this.domaine= null;
        this.x_eb_role = null;
    }

}
```

user.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription, from, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { CreateService } from 'src/app/services/create.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs';
import { eb_user } from 'src/app/classes/eb_user';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Statique } from 'src/app/utils/Statique';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private users: eb_user[];
    userSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private createService: CreateService,
              private http: HttpClient) {
       }

  getUsers() : void{
    this.createService.getUsers()
        .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.users = [];

  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log(this.users)
  }

}
```

users.component.html file:

```
<ul class="list-group"   style= "margin-top: 150px;">
  <li style="display: block;"><a routerLink="/create-user"> <button class="btn btn-primary">Create User</button></a></li><br>
</ul>

<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <th> id</th>
    <th> nom</th>
    <th>prénom</th>
    <th>tel</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>domaine</th>
  </tr>
  <tr li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
    <td>{{user.prenom}}</td>
    <td>{{user.tel}}</td>
    <td>{{user.mail}}</td>
    <td>{{user.domaine}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I expect all users registered in the database to be displayed when doing getUsers ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove **private** from users declaration and then it should work.

Replace this:

```
private users: eb_user[];
```

By this:

```
users: eb_user[];
```

And then update your constructor by this:-

```
constructor(private createService: CreateService,
              private http: HttpClient) {
   this.getUsers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, all the users will be requested from the db at the method:

```
getUsers();
```

but you never call it. It is better to put the code:

```
this.createService.getUsers()
        .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
```

to the constructor. So the data will be automatically downloaded.

Comment: I modified the code here  `constructor(private createService: CreateService,
              private http: HttpClient) {
                this.createService.getUsers()
                    .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
       }`   but the information does not get fixed.